# escaping . (dot) in gradle string

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to change the output file name when creating Android builds. Here's the code that I am using for this

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def buildDate = getDate()
        outputFileName = "$variant.applicationId-$buildDate-$variant.buildType.name"
    }
}
```

It works fine, but the output file doesn't have the `.apk` extension. So I tried to add it by adding .apk in the end

```
outputFileName ="$variant.applicationId-$buildDate-$variant.buildType.name.apk"
```

Which obviously didn't work. It generated the following error -

```
No such property: apk for class: java.lang.String
```

Then I tried to add `\\` before `.apk` which worked, but generated an extra `\` before `.apk`. Same with `\$`. I can add a blank space before `.apk`, but the file name will have a space in it.

My classpath is set as -

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

So my question is how can I escape the dot character and just print it as it is.

Comment: did you tried wrapping your variables in {}?

Comment: @SarthakMittal Can you post it as an answer. Wrapping does work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I think is happening, is that `gradle` is getting confused whether it is a complete name of your variable or a plain `String`.

One solution would be to wrap your variables inside curly braces, like so:

```
"${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
```

Answer (score 1):

So, one of my colleagues just walked in and suggested me this way (He doesn't even work in Android or Java)

```
outputFileName = "$variant.applicationId-$buildDate-$variant.buildType.name"+".apk"
```

And it worked. So silly of me :-/

**Alternative Approach:**
In the end, I have used the following way (thanks to [Sarthak Mittal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4269149/sarthak-mittal)):

```
outputFileName = "${variant.applicationId}-${buildDate}-${variant.buildType.name}.apk"
```

Comment: that collegue beat me by 30 secs :-)

Comment: Lol ok thx. I am not sure if this is the most elegant way, but I would have done the same ;-)

Comment: You should follow the other answer. Using concatenation is pretty ugly in this case and unnecessarily costs performance. ;-)

Comment: @Vampire I have used the curly braces approach, but it's certainly one of the way.

Comment: @noob I would have have used the very same approach, if I hadn't picked the other one from kotlin. :)